# Moved Magento to other server. I see home page but getting errors. What can be wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, local.xml

I had a Magento webshop 1.9.1 for a client and about 6 months ago they asked me to remove it, so i did.

I created a DB backup and also the same with the files.

Now they asked me if i was able to re-install (yep, i know...).

Recently i changed servers and i am now on php 5.6.14 and MySql 5.6 instead of the previous php 5.4 and Maria DB (don't recall version)

Now is uploaded the files and imported the DB. Changed urls in DB. I check the website and it shows the front page just as i left it ;-)

But... when clicking a menu item, page or other link, i get 404 not found, requested doc not found on this server.

what might be wrong?

Could it be this setting in local.xml?

also when trying to go in admin, it doesn't recognize that url either.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your .htaccess and remove cache manually

Comment: Hi, i removed cache already, otherwise i didn't get anything. But what would i specifically be looking for in htaccess? Also my htaccess is .text, not .htaccess?

Comment: i renamed the htaccess.txt to .htaccess and now it works :-) You are my hero... sorry but i'm not a great looking girl but a bold guy hahaha ;-)